# SQLite query for matching one column with multiple values

Tags: android, mysql, android-room

I am developing android app using **RoomDB**.

In a table there is a column called `category`

Assuming the `category` has the values from A,B,C....Z

So i have 24 `category`

For filtering category A, My query will be **where category=:A** (ONE FILTER)

for filtering A and B , Then it will be **where category=:A or category=:B**(TWO FILTER)

My filtering column can be random it may be one,two or three and so on...

Is there any **query** to **filter** these type of case.

I tried **REGEXP** but roomDB not accepting that

Waiting for good solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can use `in` clause separated by all categories

Comment: Hey thanks! i have used in clause in wrong way. I have sent string like this 'string1,string2,string3' but the correct format is 'string1','string2','string3'

Comment: I have added the answer from future perspective, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in` clause like this

```
select * from emp where dept in ('IT','HR','FIN');
```

If you have a pattern to search you can use `like` clause

```
select * from emp where name like ('%I%');
```

This will give you all employees having I in their name.